# Check for duplicates in a tuple-list

Tags: c#, list, tuples

I'm trying to find duplicates in my List of Tuples. Here's how my code is build:

```
List<(string Surname, string Name)>

var list = new List<(string, string)>();

        //..
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            list.Add((reader["Surname"], reader["Name"]));
        };
```

Example how the list can look like:

```
a1 Sara
a2 Adam
a3 Eva
a4 Adam
a5 Ragnar
```

Is there's any good way to find duplicates of `name`, and then add the `Surname` next to it:

```
Sara
Adam a2
Eva
Adam a4
Ragnar
```

Comment: So you want to only print the surname when there is a duplicate?

Comment: instead just printing `Name`(as I currently do), I would like to add `Surname` next to `Name`

Comment: You want to add Surname to everything in the list, or only the _duplicates_ ?  Your question is unclear, you haven't even shown us the code that prints the name

Comment: What if there are more than 2 duplicates of the same name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that if there are multiple duplicates with the same Name that you wish to list all such duplicates, with an approach similar to Gilad's, you could:

- Group By Name
- Exclude 'self' from the duplicate check
- Join + Delimit all the duplicates
- Flatten out the group again with SelectMany

Like so:

```
var result = list.GroupBy(item => item.Name)
                 .SelectMany(grp => grp.Select(x => 
                 (Name: x.Name, 
                  Dupes: string.Join(",", 
                     grp.Select(y => y.Surname)
                        .Except(new[]{x.Surname})))))
                 .ToList();
```

Example Input:

```
var list = new List<(string Surname, string Name)>
{
    ("a1","Sara"),
    ("a2","Adam"),
    ("a3","Eva"),
    ("a4","Adam"),
    ("a5","Ragnar"),
    ("a6","Adam"),
};
```

Example Output

```
Name    Dupes
----    -----
Sara
Adam    a4,a6 
Adam    a2,a6 
Adam    a2,a4 
Eva   
Ragnar
```

Note that the ordering will be lost due to the grouping

Answer (score 1):

You should group by the `Name` and then check the amount of items in group to project the name or full name:

```
var result = list.GroupBy(item => item.Name)
                 .SelectMany(g => g.Select(item => g.Skip(1).Any() ? 
                     $"{item.Name} {item.Surname}" : item.Name))
                 .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a second list of a tuple (string, Int) with all unique names and the count of these names. When you write the names later, if the count of that second list if bigger than 1, just append the surname.